# Write the following statement "P" using implication and its negation and explain which one is true.

Tags: logic

P: "Every graph with at least 2 vertices, all of which have a positive degree, is connected"

I was thinking that the implication could be:
"If every graph has at least two vertices, such that all of the vertices have a positive degree, then the graph is connected"

And for the negation I thought the answer is:
"There exists a graph with at least 2 vertices, where the vertices have a positive degree, such that the graph is not connected."

I am unsure of my answers and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: What is meant by "the implication of P"? Can you give another example?

Comment: Your negation is correct.

Comment: consider the statement:"For every prime number p there is another prime number q with q>p. The implication of this statement is: "If P is prime then there exists a prime q such that q>p". These "if P then Q" statements are called implications

Comment: Maybe a little bit better: "For every graph $G$, if $G$ has at least two vertices of positive degree, then $G$ is connected". And similar for the negation: "There exists a graph $G$ with at least 2 vertices of positive degree, such that $G$ is **not** connected."

Comment: Oh, okay, so what's meant is the implication inside the universal quantifier. Never seen it used that way.

Comment: In that case, your formalization is not correct, because the "every" should not be part of the implication; instead, use a parameter like $p$ in your example: "If $G$ has at least two vertices and all of the vertices have a positive degree then $G$ is connected".

Comment: Then  according to this implication, is it okay to conclude that statement P is false?